# How is it I get a Bad state: future is already completed while running a transaction?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Calling my function:

```dart
  try {
      // Add one view to the ad
      await _ad.transactionStoreAddOneToViewCount(
          viewingUser: widget.watchingUser);
```

Makes this error to be triggered:

> flutter: Error: Bad state: Future already completed

My function implementation is as follows:

```dart
  /// Transaction: add one to the count view, which is a 2-step process:
  /// 1) increment the ad view count
  /// 2) add one document to the ClassifiedAdSeen collection
  Future<void> transactionStoreAddOneToViewCount(
      {required User? viewingUser}) async {
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    // = Open a transaction to perform both operations
    return fs.runTransaction((t) async {
      /// Reads the ad document
      final adDoc = await fs.collection(collectionName).doc(id).get();

      // = Increment view count
      t.update(adDoc.reference, {"viewCount": FieldValue.increment(1)});

      // Add one line in the ad seen collection
      await ClassifiedAdView.storeCreate(
        ad: this,
        loggedUser: viewingUser,
      );

      // Reflect the change locally: TODO: is it what I should do?
      viewCount += 1;
    });
  }
```

[UPDATE] Here is the `ClassifiedAdView.storeCreate` implementation which adds a record in the related collection whenever someone sees the ad, as follows:

```dart
  /// Creates an ad-view time stamped record in the database and returns the document [id].
  static Future<String?> storeCreate(
      {required ClassifiedAd ad, required User? loggedUser}) async {
    // Don't let users count againt their own ads
    if (ad.ownerUid == loggedUser?.id) return null;

    // = Actually store the document
    final ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .add({"adId": ad.id, "userId": loggedUser?.id, "on": Timestamp.now()});

    // = Returns the document ID
    return ref.id;
  }
```

Comment: What does `ClassifiedAdView.storeCreate` do? And if that's relevant to the Firestore transaction, it should probably work on `t` too. In general: is there a way you can reproduce the problem with a single code snippet with no external dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is the cause of the error message, but you should get the document from the transaction to ensure it becomes part of that transaction. So:

```
return fs.runTransaction((t) async {
  /// Reads the ad document
  final adDoc = await t.get(fs.collection(collectionName).doc(id));
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, though it does not solve my issue you pinpoint a flaw in my code refactor. Thanks again.